# Access encrypted internal storage without touch

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, encryption

Is there a way to access the encrypted internal storage without using the display?

I damaged the display of my nexus 4 (Android 4.4, cm-11-20140104-SNAPSHOT-M2-mako) and need to access the encrypted storage to do some backup. `adb shell` is working in recovery mode.

Comment: What is it about people damaging screens and then trying to get adb backup out of it, there's seems to be a trend here... :) Use the search facility...

Comment: I find information only about backing up unencrypted devices.

Comment: There you go, [similar question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/will-a-custom-recovery-work-with-an-encrypted-device?lq=1) Searching took 5seconds tops...

Comment: I also found this question (and this https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19286/will-a-custom-recovery-work-with-an-encrypted-device?lq=1). But it doesn't solve my problem...